# Collection of undefined type

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to make a function that can retrieve tables from my database, using the table name.
I've got it working using a DataTable, but I would much prefer using an ObservableCollection/List because I can then use it in a ListCollectionView to use it's grouping possibilities in a DataGrid in WPF.

However I'm now facing the problem that the function I made in my DataManager class, should return collections of diffirent types corresponding to the table. How can I define an ObservableCollection/List where the type is defined when it is created?

Example function (this doesn't work, but might explain what I'm trying to do):

```
...
    public ObservableCollection<object> GetTable(string name)
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> table = null;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "PriceList":
                table = new ObservableCollection<PriceItem>();
                //Business logic
                break;
            case "CustomerTable":
                table = new ObservableCollection<Customer>();
                //Business logic
                break;
        }

        return table;
    }
...
```

or maybe

```
...
    public ObservableCollection<object> GetTable(string name)
    {
        ObservableCollection<object> table;

        switch (name)
        {
            case "PriceList":
                table = getPriceList();
                break;
            case "CustomerTable":
                table = getCustomers();
                break;
        }

        return table;
    }

    private ObservableCollection<PriceItem> getPriceList()
    {
        ObservableCollection<PriceItem> table = null;

        //Bussiness logic

        return table;
    }
...
```

DRAFT OF MODIFIED METHOD (I know this is probably completely wrong):

```
    public ObservableCollection<T> GetTable<T>()
    {
        ObservableCollection<T> table = new ObservableCollection<T>();

        switch (typeof(T))
        {
            case "FarrisSeries":
                table = new ObservableCollection<FarrisSeries>();
                //Business logic
                break;
            case "FarrisSpecs":
                table = new ObservableCollection<object>();
                //Business logic
                break;
        }

        return table;
    }
```

Possible use case (I probably did this all wrong, but still, I tried :P)

```
Situation
---------

Window consists of MenuBar and a DataGrid. 
In the menu there is a DropDownButton containing 
a menu which contains a list of all table names.
Clicking any button will trigger a command that 
will load the table into the DataGrid using the
MenuItem Header as a parameter. The command will
then load the appropriate ObservableCollection
(containing Objects of type related to table name)
into the DataGrid.


Case 1:

 - User Clicks "PriceList"
 - function LoadTable("PriceList") is called
 - function retrieves PriceItems from the database
 - function returns ObservableCollection<PriceItem>
 - return is stored in the Object bound to the DataGrid

Case 2:

 - User Clicks "Customer"
 - function LoadTable("Customers") is called
 - function retrieves Customers from the database
 - function returns ObservableCollection<Customer>
 - return is stored in the Object bound to the DataGrid
```

Comment: Not possible. Present your use case so that we can offer a solution.

Comment: Can you make an interface (IDisplayable) and let the different classes implement it? This would be nicer OO style then just using object.

Comment: @Jon: Sorry but I don't have a use case, only some notes I made on paper but none involving this, my knowledge about them is still too limited to make actual usage of them.

Comment: @Daniel: The usage of object was simply to illustrate I don't know what kind of object I will have, I know this doesn't work.

Comment: @TomVandenbussche: If I get this correctly, you are trying to implement `GetTable` without having designed it first (a design would include at least a couple of use cases to illustrate usage). Don't do that, it does not end well.

Comment: @Jon: Mostly I just do this in my head, but I'll try write some example use cases down to illustrate, but I dont really know use cases that very well so expect the worst :P

Comment: @Jon: I added some use cases (well my try at is though :P) is this what you meant?

Comment: @TomVandenbussche: I had code in mind ("what I would like to be able to write") but it's OK. Seems like you want to return an `IList` (or even just an `object`) -- it will be good enough for binding.

Comment: @Jon Yes you're right, I was kind of confused since this is the first time I'm actually confronted with these generic and non-generic types of objects. I'm now using the non-generic IList and everything works perfect (well, almost but that's for another question). Thanks for your continued support!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two options spring to mind:

- Return the non-generic `IList` type instead of `ObservableCollection<>`. I expect binding will still work out that the *actual* type is `ObservableCollection<>` and be able to observe changes.
- Make the method generic, and get rid of the name parameter entirely: work out the collection to fetch based on the type argument. (This feels somewhat ugly to me, as it wouldn't be truly generic, in all likelihood - you'd have a limited set of types you could use.)

Comment: Ok so I managed to make the method generic (I've never been in this part of OO programming), but I don't understand what you mean with getting the type argument. I tried typeof(T) but that doesn't seem to work (added code above). However this new stuff made me see new possibilities, so I'll keep trying and post here if I make more progress. Thanks much for the quick answer though! :)

Comment: @TomVandenbussche Why not just go for the first option. Just change your method's return type to `IList` or `ICollection` and you're done.

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't really understand what you meant by non-generic IList (and VS didn't give me much information), but now I found out what it is I works perfect! Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to make a function that can retrieve tables from my
>   database, using the table name. I've got it working using a DataTable,
>   but I would much prefer using an ObservableCollection/List because I
>   can then use it in a ListCollectionView to use it's grouping
>   possibilities in a DataGrid in WPF.

to answer this i have created a sample. check it out. i am using Northwind db for this. this provide the customer datatable loading into DataGrid and grouping on the fly.

to use this you can simple call you tables on the basis of table name from the database and then  pass this table result into Datagrid as itemsource to get the grouping on it have have created a textbox on which you provide the grouping name. on the lost focus the grouping get reflected on the Datagrid. try this and if you have any query let me know.

```
<Window x:Class="TempTest.DataTableTest"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="DataTableTest"
        Width="548"
        Height="292">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                        <Expander x:Name="exp"
                                  Background="White"
                                  Foreground="Black"
                                  IsExpanded="True">
                            <Expander.Header>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Job Title}" />
                            </Expander.Header>
                            <ItemsPresenter />
                        </Expander>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="210*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid Name="dataGrid1"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="true">
            <DataGrid.GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupHeaderStyle}">
                    <GroupStyle.Panel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <DataGridRowsPresenter />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.Panel>
                </GroupStyle>
            </DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        </DataGrid>
        <Button Name="button1"
                Width="56"
                Height="25"
                Margin="458,9,0,0"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Top"
                Click="button1_Click"
                Content="Button" />
        <TextBox Name="textBox1"
                 Width="123"
                 Height="24"
                 Margin="18,10,0,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox Name="textBox2"
                 Width="123"
                 Height="24"
                 Margin="147,10,0,0"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                 VerticalAlignment="Top" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind for this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace TempTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for DataTableTest.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class DataTableTest : Window
    {
        public DataTableTest()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            textBox2.LostFocus += new RoutedEventHandler(textBox2_LostFocus);
        }

        void textBox2_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(textBox2.Text))
            {
                var cv = dataGrid1.ItemsSource as CollectionView;
                if (cv != null)
                {
                    cv.GroupDescriptions.Clear();
                    cv.GroupDescriptions.Add(new PropertyGroupDescription(textBox2.Text));
                }

            }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


            if (textBox1.Text.Equals("customers", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Data.Northwind_2007DataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter c = new Data.Northwind_2007DataSetTableAdapters.CustomersTableAdapter();
                dt = c.GetData();
            }
            else if (textBox1.Text.Equals("employees", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                Data.Northwind_2007DataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter emp = new Data.Northwind_2007DataSetTableAdapters.EmployeesTableAdapter();
                dt = emp.GetData();
            }


            dataGrid1.ItemsSource = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(dt.DefaultView);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but since I'm working in an MVVM pattern, this is not really what I'm looking for..

Comment: I know, but after all this hastle of learning about ObservableCollections and Generic vs Non-Generic ILists, I'm staying with those classes instead of the DataTable ones. Your help is much appreciated though!